# ClearCase UCM: Get latest version from Dev-stream

Tags: clearcase-ucm, config-spec

I'm stuck over the config spec for a dynamic view.
I try to get the latest version of a folder of a UCM stream from the Dev-stream into another (Base) dynamic view.
My idea would have been to do a

```
element PathToFolder/... .../DEV-STREAM-NAME/LATEST
```

but that won't give me anything in the view.
The config spec that is automatically generated by UCM does not help me as it specifies a specific baseline and creates a branch once you check out a file (which I of course do not want, I only need read-access to the version).
Is it possible to access the latest version from the Dev-stream, or do I have to skip the folder altogether in the config spec and just copy it using the operating system (which would be possible but takes quite long as the folder might be quite large)?
Thanks for any answers and Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the *parent* folders are selected as well:

```
element vob/... .../DEV-STREAM-NAME/LATEST
element vob/path/... .../DEV-STREAM-NAME/LATEST
element vob/path/to/... .../DEV-STREAM-NAME/LATEST
element vob/path/to/folder/... .../DEV-STREAM-NAME/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

If one of the parent folder has no version in `DEV-STREAM-NAME`, but a version in the *parent* stream (like `INT-STREAM-NAME`), you would need to select that as well.

```
element vob/path/to/... .../INT-STREAM-NAME/LATEST
```

Comment: Acutally that should be the case.<br>When I replace the DEV-STREAM-NAME with the INT-STREAM-NAME I see content in the view. But I'll have a look again and post here if I still encounter the problem. Thanks for the help!