# Config spec for UCM components

Tags: clearcase-ucm, config-spec

this is kind of a follow up to this question: [ClearCase UCM: Get latest version from Dev-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783985/clearcase-ucm-get-latest-version-from-dev-stream)

I need a dynamic view to have the LATEST (or CHECKED_OUT) version of certain components of a UCM VOB and at the same time specific baselines for other components. 
For components where I want to include a specific baseline I can just include them with

`element component_1/... BASELINE`
where BASELINE is just a name of a baseline (without the need to specify a stream or anything).
The folder of the component is later included by a `element * /main/LATEST`-directive (at least to my knowledge).
As mentioned in the above mentioned link I can also add a line like
`element component_2/... /main/INT-STREAM/DEV-STREAM/LATEST`
 which should give me the latest version of DEV-STREAM.
Now I found out that sometimes (when the DEV-STREAM was 'branched' from version /main/0 I need a 
`element component_2/... /main/DEV-STREAM/LATEST`
to get the latest version of this component. And in other cases there is no DEV-STREAM (because the file was obviously never changed and therefore the DEV-STREAM is not created), so I need a third line
`element component_2/... /main/INT-STREAM/LATEST`.
And the same applies to version CHECKED_OUT.
As I want to create the config spec by script I would either need to find out where the component_2 is located (in the INT-STREAM or the DEV-STREAM) and where the DEV-STREAM was branched off or I would have to include 6 lines (one of them should match) for each component - in comparison to the one line for the baseline. Obviously I wouldn't want to include each file (there are VERY many) but would like to be able to simply specify the component with all its subfolders, just like for the baseline.
Thanks for reading - and obviously for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid all those multiple rules with:

```
element component_2/... .../DEV-STREAM/LATEST
element component_2/... .../INT-STREAM/LATEST -mkbranch DEV-STREAM
```

The order is important, and the '`...`' allows you to select a branch without knowing of its exact parent branch.

Comment: Hi, wasn't aware of the ... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: One more thing: How about CHECKEDOUT files? I thought I simply might need a element component_2/... CHECKEDOUT before the two rules from you but I still don't get the checked out version of the files. I think the problem is that the files are not checked out in the current view but in the dev-view. But how do I select them? I also tried it with .../DEV-VIEW/CHECKEDOUT but that does not help either.

Comment: @user2606240 no need for complex rules: simply add an `element * CHECKEDOUT` at the top of your config spec.

Comment: Unfortunately not... I have a file (version 18) checked out in my dev-stream and when I add the element * CHECKEDOUT at the top of the config spec I still get version 17 of this file in the view. Additionally I don't want to have all checked out files (of other components) in the view, only the one where I don't specify a baseline. So my approach would be to add the element * CHECKEDOUT after all modules specifying baselines - but as mentioned above this does not work

Comment: @user2606240 the order is important: a "CHECKEDOUT" rule must comes first. And yes, those files must be checked out in your current view

Comment: Hm. So there is no way to have checked out files from a different view (my dev-view) in another view (a temporary dynamic view)? Then I will have to think about a different approach for those files. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: @user2606240 yes, a config spec is local to a (snapshot or dynamic view).